# To combine the data from different tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column which is present in 4 different tables. The data of this column will differ from each table. It may contain some duplicates as well. Now I want to extract the unique data for this column from all 4 tables.

Note: I don't want to compare the values of other columns in any of the tables. Just the distinct data for this column is needed.

Eg:

```
Table 1: a, b, c
table 2: a, d, e
table 3: a, f, g
table 4: a, h, i
```

result :

```
a
-----------
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: Is the missing comma before the `i` in table 4 a typo or are there really elements that are delimited by space rather than a comma?

Comment: Oops the comma is missing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`. Assuming you don't need efficient query. Try below:

```
select a from t1 union
select a from t2 union
select a from t3 union
select a from t4
```

Comment: I am not getting distinct data using above query . 

to be more specific ,consider below is the data for each table and column
t1 = a(1,2,3,4)
t2 = a(2,3,6,7)
t3 = a (7,1,9)
t4= a(8,1)

result should be a(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9)

Comment: I got it. You need unique from all the tables. Try updated query.